# Create DLQ per-consumer in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I'm consuming messages from an ActiveMQ Artemis topic using JMS. My consumers are connecting directly to the FQQN of their consumer queues. Like this:

```java
jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("Transactions.Client1::ConsumerA");
```

And the configuration in the `broker.xml` is:

```xml
<address-setting match="Transactions.*">
    <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
    <dead-letter-address>Transactions.Retry</dead-letter-address>
</address-setting>
```

But then, the name of the DLQ will be `DLQ.Transactions.Client1`, without the consumer name.

What I need is that each consumer has its own DLQ. Something like `DLQ.Transactions.Client1.ConsumerA`. Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

When I say "consumer", it may (actually) be more like a "consumer group". For example, `ConsumerA` and `ConsumerB` are two totally different applications, with (possibly) multiple running instances and managed by its own team. That's why I want a different DLQ for each one.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using FQQN? It's not really normal to need FQQN with traditional JMS use-cases.

Comment: @JustinBertram, I know I could use a shared topic subscription to achieve similar effect, but I couldn't find a way to do that using JmsTemplate, which is what the class JmsItemReader (from Spring Batch) uses. Even if I manage to fix that, it won't help me with this naming problem, isn't it?

Comment: Are you tightly restricted to just what Spring Batch offers? Are you not able to use the JMS API directly?

Comment: Not really restricted, but we have a bunch of batch jobs that reads from a shared database table and are being (partially) rewritten to read from a topic. So it would be less rework and less risky to stay in Spring Batch. But, if necessary, we can change that. This option is not discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to configure the broker to auto-create a dead-letter queue whose name contains the name of the queue where the message was originally sent. As noted in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html#automatically-creating-dead-letter-resources), the dead-letter queue is named according to the *address* where the message was originally sent along with any configured prefix and/or suffix.

However, the message itself will have a property named `_AMQ_ORIG_QUEUE` which will contain the name of the queue where the message was originally routed. This means you can use a consumer with a message selector (e.g. `_AMQ_ORIG_QUEUE = 'ConsumerA'`) so that the consumer will *only* receive messages which were originally routed to a particular queue. This is *functionally equivalent* to having a dead-letter queue per-queue.

For what it's worth, what you're calling the "consumer name" isn't the name of the consumer at all, at least not from the broker's point of view. It's just the name of the queue.

Ultimately it's just not possible to configure a dead-letter queue per-queue. It's only possible to configure a dead-letter queue per address. This is true whether the resources are create manually (e.g. via `broker.xml`) or automatically.

Comment: I need one queue per consumer, but also one DLQ per consumer. If I understood correctly, the only way to have that is to put the consumer name on the original address, like `Transactions.Client1.ConsumerA`. But the producer behavior shouldn't be changed, it should just keep posting to a topic. In that case, what are my options?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question. In short, it's just not possible to have a dead-letter queue per-queue. If you change the address then you'd have to change all your clients which are sending messages to that address and consuming from the FQQN.

Comment: What's your use-case that requires a dead-letter queue per-queue?

Comment: I updated my question to clarify the use case. When I said "queue per consumer" it's because each "consumer" (or consumer group) is a different batch application. The only thing they have in common is that they all start reading from the same topic. Maybe my error was mapping each application as a real consumer of the topic. But what else could I have done?

Comment: I just updated my answer with more details about using a message selector. I think that may be a viable solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Justin Bertram's answer is probably what most people should do. It is what I would have done if wasn't for the requirements of having different dead letter address and expiry address per consumer application.

In my case, I solved it using [Diverts](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.19.0/diverts.html).

First, the producer wasn't changed. It keeps posting to the topic `Transactions.Client1`.

Then, I configured a divert in the `broker.xml` file:

```xml
<divert name="Transactions.Divert">
    <address>Transactions.Client1</address>
    <forwarding-address>Transactions.Client1.ConsumerA</forwarding-address>
    <exclusive>false</exclusive>
</divert>
```

**IMPORTANT:**
The downside is that it doesn't scale. If I have N clients and M consumers, I'll have N×M diverts.

Then, the address-settings was changed to (note the two asterisks in the match attribute):

```xml
<address-setting match="Transactions.*.*">
    <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
    <dead-letter-address>Transactions.Retry</dead-letter-address>
</address-setting>
```

So, when the processing of a message fails, at the address `Transactions.Retry` will be created a queue named `DLQ.Transactions.Client1.ConsumerA`.

And everybody is happy, except the ops guy, who will have to configure more than a hundred diverts in production. I hope his vim-fu is OK.

PS: Just a tip: Always divert to addresses with same prefix (in the example it is "Transactions"). It will make your life much easier when you have to configure a cluster in production.

Comment: Did you try using selectors with the `_AMQ_ORIG_QUEUE` property as I outlined? That should give you the behavior you want and it will scale much better. I briefly considered diverts for your use-case, but it seems like a complete maintenance nightmare. It's certainly not clear from your answer why you would choose diverts over selectors.